# Phalcon Custom Tag template

Tags: phalcon

Is there any way to create a view for custom tag in Phalcon so I can just pass the parameters to be rendered?

```
class MenuModule extends \Phalcon\Tag {
    public static function initialize($param) {
        return $param;
    }
}
```

In my view I can call

```
echo MenuModule::initialize('Home Page');
```

What I want to do is to pass array like:

```
$menu = array('Home','About','Contact');
echo MenuModule::initialize($menu);
```

And then in Tag Helper to call a subview to render that array instead of something like this:

```
class MenuModule extends \Phalcon\Tag {
    public static function initialize($param) {
        $menu = '<ul>';
        foreach($param as $p) {
            $menu .= '<li>' . $p . '</li>';
        }
        $menu .= '</ul>';
        return $menu;
    }
}
```

This is not that complex, but I want to use views instead of generating HTML inside PHP because of a larger HTML files.

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, [Tag Service](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tags.html#tag-service) and [Creating your own helpers](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tags.html#creating-your-own-helpers) on official Phalcon documentation.

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Tag;

class MenuModule extends Tag {
    static public function initialize($param) {
        $menu = '<ul>';
        foreach($param as $p) {
            $menu .= '<li>' . $p . '</li>';
        }
        $menu .= '</ul>';

        return $menu;
    }
}
```

Then change the definition of the service ‘tag’:

```
$di['tag'] = function () {
    return new MenuModule();
};
```

And then in volt access it like:

```
{{ MenuModule::initialize($param) }}
```

Comment: Where is it "Then change the definition of the service ‘tag’" ?